# nginx referer log

Tags: nginx

Does nginx has apache's equivalent to a referer log? For apache, you can have something like

```
Customlogs logs/referer_log referer
```

Basically I'd like to know who's referring traffic to my nginx server. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked these sites ?

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule

http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/8/27/customizing-nginx-web-logs

Comment: first link doesnt work. Why not include an answer instead of linking around?